# List of tables in a Database

Tags: python, database, null, databricks, azure-databricks

I achieved to have a DataFrame with all the columns and their type of all the tables in my database of Databricks.

| Database | Table | Column | ColumnType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | table1 | column1 | string |
| default | table1 | column2 | boolean |
| default | table2 | column3 | integer |
| default | table2 | column4 | string |
| default | table2 | column5 | string |

Could anybody help me to add two extra columns, one column that indicates the number of null values of each column in each table and another column that indicates the percentage of null values of each column in each table?

| Database | Table | Column | ColumnType | Nulls | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | table1 | column1 | string | 345 | 5% |
| default | table1 | column2 | boolean | 0 | 0% |
| default | table2 | column3 | integer | 98760 | 90% |
| default | table2 | column4 | string | 56721 | 52% |
| default | table2 | column5 | string | 1512 | 1% |

Thanks in advance!

Python-Code:

```
table_name = 'table1'
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM {}".format(table_name))
col_null_cnt_df = df.select([count(when(col(c).isNull(),c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
col_null_cnt_df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

- I have the following data in my 2 tables `t1 and t2`.

[image]

- The following is how I have the data in my dataframe:

[image]

- I have used the following code to get the desired output. First, I have created 2 columns containing respective queries:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,col,concat_ws 
df = df.withColumn('count_of_nulls',concat(lit('select * from '),concat_ws('.',*['Database','Table']),lit(' where isnull('),col('Column'),lit(')')))

df = df.withColumn('no_of_rows',concat(lit('select * from '),concat_ws('.',*['Database','Table'])))
```

[image]

- Now, I converted this dataframe to pandas dataframe on spark API to perform respective operations using loops and update the dataframe:

```
pdf  = df.to_pandas_on_spark()
#pdf

null_count = []
total_count = []
for i in pdf['count_of_nulls'].to_numpy():
    null_count.append(spark.sql(i).count())


for i in pdf['no_of_rows'].to_numpy():
    total_count.append(spark.sql(i).count())
    
print(null_count,total_count)
pdf['count_of_nulls'] = null_count
pdf['no_of_rows'] = total_count
#pdf
```

[image]

- I converted it back to pyspark dataframe and then calculated percentage.

```
df = pdf.to_spark()
df.withColumn('percentage_of_nulls', col('count_of_nulls')/col('no_of_rows')*100).show()
```

[image]